# Packaging a sencha touch2 application on Blackberry10 webworks

Tags: sencha-touch-2, packaging, blackberry-webworks

How to package a sencha touch application on Blackberry10 webworks?
I am new to blackberry application development please help me out in packaging the application? i dont want to use phonegap as mediator for packaging sencha touch application in BB10

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions on how to build a Sencha Touch application for BlackBerry 10:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/creating_blackberry_webworks_applications_with_sencha_touch.html

Summary:

1. Use Sencha SDK to compile your app
2. Create a config.xml file
   (necessary for WebWorks)
3. Package your application using the
   BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK.